# GPIO LED Python

Tags: gpio, pi-2, python-3

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I found this [guide](https://www.pythonprogramming.net/gpio-raspberry-pi-tutorials/) on  but it's not working for me. The program does not output any errors but the LED doesn't light up.

I have and LED with + on `GPIO 12` and - on `GPIO 6` with a 100 Ohm resistor. This is shown in the images below:

[image: https://ibb.co/WVmBQxc]

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12,GPIO.HIGH)

time.sleep(3)

GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by changing 12 to 18... however when I count the pins it is actually 12? Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

Thats because by using 'GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)' you are specifying the BCM  numbering convention. GPIO 18 is actual pin number 12.

[image]